# Add non-template HTML to crispy forms layout

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a dynamic formset (using crispy forms) to set prices for objects. I need to display the name of these objects to users, so they know which object they're setting the price for. However, these names are chosen by the users themselves in a different form. It seems most obvious to use the HTML class for this (inside Layout), but that's for rendering Django templates. Letting users add template code leads to security issues.

One solution I thought of is manually "escaping" it first, e.g. by wrapping it in a `{% verbatim XXXXXX %}` tag, with `XXXXXX` some securely random string, or by replacing any curly brace by its HTML character code. But both of these solutions seem pretty hacky and prone to mistakes and thus security issues.

Is there a cleaner way to insert pure HTML into a crispy forms Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to build your own crispy layout objects, they only need a render function that returns the string to be inserted into the form. You can write your own version of the HTML class like this:

```
class SafeHTML:
    def __init__(self, html):
        self.html = html

    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(self.html)
```